# Custom scrollbar in div

Tags: jquery, css, html, interface, scroll

[image]

I'm stuck with this situation. I have a request to make a div content with scrollbar (design is in image). I have searched and found only one method is fit: [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller) but it's quite complex and hard to use. So I want to ask if there's some other way to do the same thing like that. Thanks you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what is hard to use about that plugin? It's pretty straight forward and documented

Comment: *complex and hard* does not help us understand the problem.

Comment: Just never mind. I'm in deadline and I can't read it carefully. What I need now is more simple way to sort this problem. After this project I will sit back try to use this plugin. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) is the best in my opinion

[This demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html) shows that you can use nested scrollbars without a problem.

I've done it before. There is a slight learning curve to using jscrollpane but it's worth it.

### EDIT

I've just looked at the demo scrollbar you linked to. I used it before. It works well but I preferred jscrollpane as I didn't find any limitations with it. But to answer your question, there is no easy way of having a custom scrollbar like in your image. You would need to use one of these two plugins (or other). The hard part is actually styling the scrollbar with CSS. The initialization is pretty straight forward.

Comment: +1 yes there is a learning curve. If you load the content into the div via ajax. then you will have to reinstate the scroll pane

Comment: Yep! That's why he site has a good documentation and many example!